# One codebase, two clients, two versions of a Doctrine ORM entity

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I have an app that collects data. It's a survey of sorts. The questions for the survey can be managed by a GUI tied to database tables in the app. But the actual answers to the questions get stored in a single table: observations. I've considered an EAV model instead, but let's set that aside for the moment. The Observation entity has over 900 properties because the survey has around that many questions. This has worked ok so far, even if it is a bit ugly in spots. But now I'm working on making this app power a new survey from a new client. It's key that I maintain the same codebase and the same git repository, but the app needs to accommodate another 700 observation properties. I added them to my entity and attempted to do a migration to create the new database columns. But alas, I hit an error telling me that the row size is too large. Too many columns!

The workaround I'd like to explore is to have multiple versions of the Observation entity. I could have one for each survey and use a config file to select the right one. But I want the selected entity to sit in the same spot in the ORM hierarchy. So, for example. If I call

```
$subscription->getObservation()
```

I want it to return the right kind of 
observation based on the config. It's ok if each install ends up having a table for each survey because all but one of those tables would have 0 rows.

As mentioned above, another option would be to abandon the wide-table design and use EAV. But that approach has some major downsides.

Comment: You could model questions and answers as entities? Each survey entity could then have a relationship to each. This would remove any issues with database table columns/class properties and be simply a case of changing the data for each client.

Comment: @AlexP: That's the EAV approach I mentioned and I think I will move in that direction when I have the time. For now I decided to remove that entity from version control and commit the alternate versions with non-php file extensions. So, for each install I just need to copy the correct version to the Observation.php filename. This lets each install have a different set of columns for the observations table.